# perimeter of the regtangle

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, geometry, gre-exam

if the area of rectangle is 40, which of the following could be the perimeter of the rectangle? Indicate all such areas.

A) 20

B) 40

C) 200

D)400

E)2000

F)4000

Answers are B,C,D,E,F

Comment: Okay... what's your question.

Comment: Do you want us to do your homework ? What have you attempted ?

Comment: @JeanMarie what a trival comment!! as it is seen, there is gre exam tag. I prepared it by myself. And I want to see the easy / short  solution way of it.

Comment: The rectangle could be approximately square, making the minimum $4\sqrt {40}$.  The perimeter must be at least 25, but it could be extremely skinny, and there is no upper bound.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose the length of the rectangle is $x$ and the width of the rectangle is $y$.Write your given information in terms of algebra:

$$xy=40$$

$$x+x+y+y=2x+2y=P$$

Of course we have:

$$x > 0, y > 0$$

Now use the first equation to solve for $y$ and write the equation of the perimeter in terms of only $x$.

Minimize and maximize the perimeter using standard methods $f'(x)=0$ and noting the end behaviors.

> $$y=\frac{40}{x}$$. 
> $$P=2x+\frac{80}{x}$$. 
> $$x \to 0^+ \implies P \to \infty, x \to \infty  \implies P \to \infty$$. 
> Now let's solve for the minimum:
> $$f'(x)=0 \implies 2-\frac{80}{x^2}=0 \implies x=\pm \sqrt{40}=\pm 2\sqrt{10}$$. 
> $$x > 0 \implies x=2\sqrt{10} \implies \text{min}(P)=4\sqrt{10}+\frac{80}{2\sqrt{10}}=8\sqrt{10}$$ considering our already evaluated end behaviors on our domain $x \in (0,\infty)$.
>  Above I multiplied by the fraction $\frac{80}{2\sqrt{10}}$ by $\frac{\sqrt{10}}{\sqrt{10}}=1$ to take the square root out of the denominator.
> Hence our only constraint on the perimeter is $P \geq 8\sqrt{10}$. 
>  Without a calculator you can figure $8(4)>8\sqrt{10}>8(3)$ from which you can eliminate the answer you need to eliminate and keep the answers you need to keep.

Comment: I read your comment and your looking for an easier way, maybe you might completing the square "easier".

Comment: As a shortcut we can prove that the rectangle of lowest perimeter given a constant for our area is a square, and use this for a lot of problems @B11b

Comment: Personally, I would have visualized the issue by first drawing the curve (hyperbola) with equation $xy=40$, (for $x,y>0$) and then try to fit rectangles with the given perimeters. If this test does not ned explanations, you can find out very quickly which answers are valid.